# Disk still full after deleting some files

Tags: disk-usage, deleted-files

I have an AWS linux instance with a root drive of 32GB.
I have an EBS mount of 20GB

On my root I ran out of space, so I cleared out some files. However my root drive is still full. I can't find out why because when I look at sizes of the directories using `du` and `ncdu` they show the drive should have a lot of space.

```
df
```

I get the following results

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      32894812 31946092    848472  98% /
devtmpfs         2017224       60   2017164   1% /dev
tmpfs            2025364        0   2025364   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdh       20511356  4459276  15003504  23% /mnt/ebs
```

My /dev/xvda1 is still full

After some research I installed a great tool *ncdu* to display disk space and the results are:

```
ncdu 1.10 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
--- / -------------------------------------           
     4.2GiB [##########] /mnt                          
     1.5GiB [###       ] /var
     1.2GiB [##        ] /usr
   684.9MiB [#         ] /opt
   464.3MiB [#         ] /home
   141.7MiB [          ] /lib
    53.5MiB [          ] /boot
    21.2MiB [          ] /lib64
    10.8MiB [          ] /sbin
     8.1MiB [          ] /bin
     7.1MiB [          ] /etc
     2.7MiB [          ] /tmp
    60.0KiB [          ] /dev
    48.0KiB [          ] /root
 e  16.0KiB [          ] /lost+found
 e   4.0KiB [          ] /srv
 e   4.0KiB [          ] /selinux
 e   4.0KiB [          ] /media
 e   4.0KiB [          ] /local
 .   0.0  B [          ] /proc
     0.0  B [          ] /sys
     0.0  B [          ]  .autofsck
```

If I `du -h` my total is 
8.3G    /

So why would my disk be 95% full when it clearly has a lot of space. Am I missing something to do with the mounts and is there any other tool I can run to find out why it is 95% full?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What did you delete? If you remove a file that is still in use by a running process (e.g., a daemon), that disk space is only released when the process is shut down/restarted.

For example, if you removed current Apache log files, the space will still be in use until you restart Apache. Similarly for system logs (those in `/var/log`).

You can either:

- Restart the process(es) in question (e.g. Apache, `syslogd`, etc).
- Restart your system.

Once you do one of the above, you should see more available space.

Comment: You are right. After restarting a process that I know I removed some files from the used space has gone to 16%  /dev/xvda1      32894812 5133296  27661268  16% /  I can see how my process went wrong. I changed the home location of a build server to a different mount and restarted the build server and once I confirmed it was running correctly I deleted the old directory. There must have still been a lock on that directory as the logs still get written there.